# In my android device when I take picture from camera, the image is reverting

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera, front-camera

I am using ASUS ZENFONE 4 - ASUS T00I, when I open camera and if I take any picture it is showing reverse image when I took image from Front camera  how can change that in settings , please suggest me

Comment: Are you saying it is taking a selfie, when you say reverse image? If so, take it out of selfie mode, which uses the rear-facing camera. When your camera is on, select the menu icon, and remove it from selfie mode.

Comment: I solved this problem in settings we have save as flipped before it is on and I changed to off mode now it is taking as a normal image from front camera

Comment: Now that you named that effect, I understand what you mean by reversing. Sort of a left-to-right reversal of objects.

Comment: In that device they are given this option like flip

Comment: On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) – so as you've obviously solved your issue, would you mind making the solution an answer (preferably with step-by-step instructions for "dummies")? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @lzzy here I make the comments that is the solution only single line how can I make it step by step procedure. just make that one as a solution.